# Multiple try-except without exec() solution

Tags: python

I have such multiple try-except

```
errors_log = set()
try:
    page_element = chrome.find_element_by_link_text("Next Page")
except Exception as e:
    errors_log.add(e)
try:
    page_element = chrome.find_element_by_class_name("pager_next")
except Exception as e:
    errors_log.add(e)
```

Following the answers from other question, I refactor the codes:

```
page_elements = ['chrome.find_element_by_link_text("Next Page")',
                 'chrome.find_element_by_class_name("pager_next")',]
for page_element in page_elements:
    try:
        exec(page_element)
    except Exception as e:
       errors_log.add(e)
```

I feel bad about it, might because using `exec()`

How could I refactor it not ugly?

---

Thanks to the Zakharov's helpful answer, I refactor codes as

```
actions = [chrome.find_element_by_class_name,
           chrome.find_element_by_link_text]
next_pages = ["pager_next ", "Next Page"]  
prev_pages = ["pager_prev ", "Prev Page"]

def get_page_element_by_multiple_tries(actions, pages):
    """
    Try different context.
    """
    for action, page in zip(actions, pages):
        try:
            page_element = action(page)
        except Exception as e:
            errors_log.add(e) 
            print(e)
    # print(errors_log)
    return page_element
```

Comment: If it really is indeterminant what you're expecting, I agree with your original approach tbh

Comment: Please tell us what other answers suggested this code, because they should really be updated and/or downvoted; there is no reason to use `exec` here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store Python functions in list as objects (because they're objects) and call them in loop:

```
actions = [chrome.find_element_by_link_text, chrome.find_element_by_class_name]
pages = ["Next Page", "pager_next"]

for action, page in zip(actions, pages):
    try:
        page_element = action(page)
    except Exception as e:
        errors_log.add(e)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
errors_log = set()
try:
    page_element = chrome.find_element_by_link_text("Next Page")
except Exception as e:
    errors_log.add(e)
    try:
        page_element = chrome.find_element_by_class_name("pager_next")
    except Exception as e1:
        errors_log.add(e1)
```

To appease those in the comments, from my perspective of the question and the code provided, the code above amends how the try blocks are handled. The original code would check for both, the code I posted will only check for the class if the link text cannot be found. E.g. if the first element he wants to select by text is the same one he wants to select by class, then if the link text is present then it will not waste time checking if the alternative exists.

Had those people in the comments been patient, they would have seen the explanation. Even if they just asked politely. For some reason people think it's their God given right to be rude to others on SO...

Comment: Please don't repost the same answer to circumvent downvotes. There's a reason your answer was downvoted in the first place, and posting an identical answer once again will not change the result.

Comment: I'm not going to engage in a debate over this, but you seem to have misinterpreted the comments. Nobody was rude, they were just objective in what they thought was incorrect with your answer. Downvotes are also not personal things, they are solely for the perceived correctness of the answer. You shouldn't take any of it personally, nor would mentioning it as you did in an answer be objective in solving the problem. If answers can't have criticism then the site just doesn't work as a repository; it's only an indication of something you can improve on.